# req.user is undefined in axios POST request but GET works just fine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, jwt

I understand similar questions has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63594293/fetch-post-request-works-but-axios-post-does-not), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59538411/axios-not-authenticating-to-api) and in a hundred other questions posts. So I will make sure to focus on the missing parts in these posts.

I have a create-react-app running on same server with a node express server with a cors configuration of:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000", 
    credentials: true,
    
  })
);
```

I would make a get request in this way:

```
Axios.get("http://localhost:8080/base/hasemail",  { withCredentials: true })
         .then(result => {
           console.log( "Has Email?",result.data)
           this.setState({
             hasEmail: result.data
           })
         })
  }
```

req.user returns the user as long as I got the `{ withCredentials: true }` in the GET request.

However in the POST request, same can't be said:

```
Axios({
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            son: 137URR,
        },
        withCredentials: true,
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/addsvj'
    })
```

I know JWT need to be implemented especially when client is on a different server. I don't have JWT implemented. Could this be the cause of req.user being undefined POST requests?

Any idea what else I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think this work...

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/base/hasemail",  { withCredentials: true })
    .then(result => {
        console.log( "Has Email?",result.data)
        this.setState({
            hasEmail: result.data
        })
    })
  }
```